# Change or Add Menu options when I click right click on Desktop

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background

Presently, when I Right-Click on the Ubuntu Desktop I get options like shown in the image[image]

Now, I want to add one more option in this menu (say "set wallpaper"). So, that when I click on the set wallpaper, Desktop wallpaper get change Automatically( taking any one wallpaper automatically from the specific folder at random)

Is there any way to do so?
If there is....!! Please help!!